# Sitemap.xml missing

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, sitemaps

I've CE 1.8.0 and cron is working, sitemap is enabled an database table cron_schedule says sitemap_generate success. But sitemap.xml file is missing? What folder it should locate? What do I miss or what would be a tip or answer to get this work?

Comment: What happens when you manually create the sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can manually generate sitemap.xml from `admin>catalog>Google Sitemap` which will resolve missing sitemap.xml  issue  and also here you find sitemap xml path and

```
Generally site map is located at yourmagento instance dir
```

Comment: Are you sure that possibility is on 1.8.0 because I can't find any button or path or anything like that on that page. There I'm only able to change settings for categories, products etc. and enable sitemap and cron time.

Comment: yes i sure .. you instance have missing files of sitemap other are some customization

Comment: who an why give me downvote?

Comment: You and brentwpeterson got me to get it work! First look for yourself, my question was "What do I miss". The missing chain was Catalog > Google sitemap :) There it is possible to generate a sitemap, not in admin. Thanks!